# Visual Studio 2015, create .edmx file for postgresql without visual studio extension

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I would like to use the .edmx designer in Visual Studio 2015 for managing objects on postgresql 12. 
I've installed:

- EntityFramework 6.2.0
- EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.2.1.1
  that in turn installs:
- Npgsql 4.0.7.0

So i thought I was ok, instead when clicking on "Project, Add New Item, ADO.NET Entity Data Model", then "EF Designer from Database" it doesn't propose any postgresql connection.

[image: Choose Data Source Dialog]

I've read about a Visual Studio integration find it [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html), in which they say that is compatible with VS 2015.

But in the Visual Studio Marketplace, find it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration), VS 2015 is not listed in the compatible products.
I tried to install it and i got the following error:

```
10/21/2019 3:07:48 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
```

at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

So it's quite clear to me that such tools introduce a whole layer of creepy dependencies in the projects beyond the already complex dependencies graph of the project's components. 
I would like to avoid this extension, but is it possible to still use the designer while writing connection stings manually? And how? Can I use code-first approach at least ?

Comment: The first link says it's compatible. Did you actually try installing it? I doubt you could easily use the EF designer without it since it likely won't know how to read the schema information from the database - that's one of the features the extension mentions it has. You'd have to write the whole edmx by hand in XML, and there would be no wizard for updating if you add fields etc in the db

Comment: Or, is there any special reason why you couldn't just use VS2017 for your project?

Comment: I added the exception that i get trying to install the .vsix.

Comment: According to the [q&a](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration&ssr=false#qna) someone is getting that error with 2017 as well. Maybe something is wrong with the vsix. Might be worth opening an issue at https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues. But perhaps you should try in 2017 first.

Comment: Honestly, I cannot base a project on something that is so buggy. And even if it's not buggy, it comes with its own set of requirements that adds up to an already complex dependencies tree. That's the reason of my question. What can I get without this extension? What do I miss if I don't use it?

Comment: you can get the pgsql driver which lets you connect to postgresql as a nuget package. If you don't install the extension then (as far as i can see) you can't use the EF designer or any of the wizards. You'd have to make your EDMX by hand, I think. Which probably removes a lot of the advantage of using EF. Seriously though...did you try using it in 2017 or 2019 before giving up?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the Npgsql.vcix from here

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/tag/v4.0.7

I've had the same problem with 4.0.10 version and it worked for me